# cpprestsdk why the floating point in C++ was inaccurate which lost precision?

Tags: visual-c++, double, precision

I was using VS 2015 and cpprestsdk version is 2.10.16, I  was trying to send a Json array with cpprestsdk ,it has problem when I tried to parse the string into json,they lost precision

```
   wstring postclinicdetailjsonwstr;
   charstarconvertwstr(post_clinic_detail, postclinicdetailjsonwstr);//convert std::string to wstring
   utility::stringstream_t s;
   s << postclinicdetailjsonwstr;
   web::json::value diseinfoarr = json::value::parse(s);
```

post_clinic_detail was a std::string ,the contents was

```
[{"medins_list_codg":"10090971","det_item_fee_sumamt":21.38,"cnt":1,"pric":21.38}]
```

afterward I tried to add this json value to antoher json and tried to serialize it,guess what ,it lost the  precision

```
   dataitem[L"feedetail"] = json::value(diseinfoarr);
   wstring jsonwstrtosend=dataitem.serialize();
```

the content of jsonwstrtosend was
......

```
[{"medins_list_codg":"10090971","det_item_fee_sumamt":21.379999999999999,"cnt":1,"pric":21.379999999999999}]
```

any idea how to deal with this kind of issue?

Comment: `21.38` does not have an exact representation in the IEEE-754 floating point format. What gets stored in the variable is the closest representable value which is [`21.3799999999999990052401699359`](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=050049046051056). If you need to roundtrip the exact values as originally read then use strings instead of floating points.

Comment: @dxiv ok cool, ty